# How do I get GPU info on Ubuntu using C#?

Tags: c#, ubuntu, gpu

I would like to know how I can get the GPU info using a C# library on an Ubuntu 18.04 system?
I am interested in parameters like number of GPUs, GPU utilization, GPU memory etc.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try OpenGL - it has cross-platform functions for getting information about the GPU such as vendor, version numbers, etc. so I would expect it also has support for getting the information you require.

It might not drill down enough to get GPU utilization/breakdown, memory etc. however - if you can't get it working through OpenGL/C# you can actually run commands from C# as if you had a terminal window open.

[This](https://loune.net/2017/06/running-shell-bash-commands-in-net-core/) explains how to set up C# to run commands on the system.

[This](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5417/how-to-get-the-gpu-info) and [this](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-find-linux-vga-video-card-ram/) explain what commands you might want to use to get the information about GPU that you need.